# How do I arbitrarily reorder lines in a text file using a Unix shell?

Tags: bash, shell, text, ksh

I've got a text file with an arbitrary number of lines, e.g.:

```
one line
some other line
an additional line
one more here
```

I'd like to write a script to reorder those lines based on a given order. e.g.

- An input of 2 1 3 4 would swap the first and second lines.
- An input of 3 1 2 4 would put the 3rd line first, the 1st line second, the 2nd line third and keep the 4th line fourth.

I could hack something together, but I'm wondering if there's an elegant solution?

I can use either bash or ksh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
for num in $input ; do
    sed $num'!d' file
done
```

Comment: `for num in ${input[@]} ; do sed "$num!d" file; done` gives error `-bash: !d": event not found`. `for num in ${input[@]} ; do sed '$num!d' file; done` gives error `sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command` where input[0]=2, input[1]=1, input[2]=3

Comment: You need to escape the `!` as `\!` when you try this interactively, because it's used for history substitution. The code he gave you should work in a script.

Comment: The escaping doesn't work interactively. I've modified choroba's code slightly to make it work both on the command line and in a script.

Comment: `for n in 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9 10 1; do sed $n'!d' /tmp/xs1.$$; done`   reorders 10 lines in a tmp file :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my @lines = <STDIN>; # Read stdin into an array
foreach my $linenum (@ARGV) { # Get the new order from argument list
  print $lines[$linenum-1];
}
```

Run the script as:

```
./scriptname 2 1 3 4 < inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
for num in "$@"; do
    awk "NF==$num" file
done
```

Bash-only (don't need to reset IFS if you are putting this in a script):

```
IFS=$'\n'
lines=( $(<file) )
for num in "$@"; do
    echo lines[num-1]
done
```